# Are we capable of building bigger high pressure cylinders?

Tags: compressed-air

Check out this 200-300 bar cylinders:

[image: 200 to 300 bar high pressure cylinders]

Is it practically possible to build a bigger cylinder of say: `10m x 1m` - and make it hold a pressure of `300 bar` in a safe way?

I can understand that bigger cylinders might not exist due to the fact that are not needed - not practical/commercial in industry to have something bigger then a human can move around - but for what im thinking, a bigger cylinder might be needed.

Can we build it with steel and using standard practices? Or we already reached some limits and this is why we settled for this cylinders with dimensions like in the picture? Sorry if this is a stupid question. Thanks :)

Comment: Seen air tanks of 5m long and 3m diameter at 10 bar... used to supply a supersonic wind tunnel..

Comment: A 300 bar steel diving cylinder is about 200mm diameter and 5m wall thickness. For the same pressure, the thickness is proportional to the diameter so a 1m diameter cylinder would have to be about 25mm thick. Products like that are commercially available.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question; The present size is the largest than can be easily moved by an average human. Otherwise pretty big "bottles" can be built; the largest I know are 10 ft diameter, 100 ft tall with 12 in. thick walls (  hydrocrackers).

Comment: Or, 30 m tall , 3 m diameter, with 300 mm walls.